# Validación de montos Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Buenas comunidad. Quiero hacer un validación en el modelo ya que necesito validar un monto donde el cliente no pueda exceder del monto que debe. Ejemplo: El monto a cancelar es 10, hago un pago de 3 queda debiendo 7. Luego quiero hacer un abono de 12 quiero que el modelo generé un error que ese no es el monto faltante ya que 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera, creas un método el cual puede ser llamado por validate, como desconozco tú código te lo pongo con variables en español espero se entienda.

```
validate :validar_monto_a_depositar

def validar_monto_a_depositar
  if monto_abonado > deuda
    errors.add(:monto_abonado, "El monto abonado es mayor, su deuda es de #{deuda}")
  end

end
```